# How to mock a CellSet object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, adomd.net

I got a method which converts [CellSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.adomdclient.cellset.aspx) to DataTable. Something like this:

```
public DataTable ConvertCellSetToDataTable(CellSet cellSet)
{
    if (cellSet == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    SetColumns(cellSet, dataTable);
    WriteValues(cellSet, dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Now I want to write unit test for this method. Normally I would use new to create an instance, but this time I don't see any public constructor method of this class.

So, is there anyway I can

1. mock a CellSet object
2. and modify it's properties, such as Axes?

Rhino.Mocks is my choice for unit test framework.

Comment: Show your method, which you want to unit test.

Comment: @Yogi Updated. I did't put the method SetColumns or WriteValues here because I think it's too detail for this question. Basically they read data from this CellSet and build data columns and assign value to datarows...

Comment: Can you show the `SetColumns` and `WriteValues` methods. Need to see what properties/methods of `CellSet` that they use. Then I can show you what to abstract so that you are not directly coupled to the `CellSet` class. The majority of the classes in the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` namespace are sealed and provide no public constructors which make them very difficult to mock/fake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mock classes/objects you don't own. In this case, because you are coupling the method(s) to `CellSet` you are now directly dependent to it.

The majority of the classes in the `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient` namespace are sealed and provide no public constructors which make them very difficult to mock/fake.

Review the `CellSet` class and determine what functionality you want from it. Extract the properties/methods you need and decide what you want to abstract behind a service you can control.

Here is a simplified example of what I just explained.

```
public class MyClassUnderTest {
    public DataTable ConvertCellSetToDataTable(ICellSetWrapper cellSet) {
        if (cellSet == null) {
            return null;
        }

        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        SetColumns(cellSet, dataTable);
        WriteValues(cellSet, dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }

    private void WriteValues(ICellSetWrapper cellSet, DataTable dataTable) {
        //...assign value to datarows
    }

    private void SetColumns(ICellSetWrapper cellSet, DataTable dataTable) {
        //...read data from this CellSet and build data columns
    }
}

public interface ICellSetWrapper {
    //...Methods and propeties exposing what you want to use
}

public class MyCellSetWrapper : ICellSetWrapper {
    CellSet cellSet;
    public MyCellSetWrapper(CellSet cellSet) {
        this.cellSet = cellSet;
    }
    //...Implemented methods/properties
}
```

You can then mock the needed functionality in order to test your method with the testing framework of your choice.